# Linq how to query a list of items for a combined list of a child collection based on a property of the parent item

Tags: c#, linq

Hi say I have the objects:

```
public class InvoiceLine
{
}
```

and

```
public class InvoiceHeader
{
    public char Group { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLines { get; set; }
}
```

Data is set up for them as follows:

```
var invoiceLine1 = new InvoiceLine();
var invoiceLine2 = new InvoiceLine();
var invoiceLine3 = new InvoiceLine();
var invoiceLine4 = new InvoiceLine();
var invoiceLine5 = new InvoiceLine();
var invoiceLine6 = new InvoiceLine();
var invoiceLine7 = new InvoiceLine();
var invoiceLine8 = new InvoiceLine();

var invoiceHeader1 = new InvoiceHeader { Group = 'A', InvoiceLines = new List<InvoiceLine> { invoiceLine1, invoiceLine2 } };
var invoiceHeader2 = new InvoiceHeader { Group = 'A', InvoiceLines = new List<InvoiceLine> { invoiceLine3, invoiceLine4 } };
var invoiceHeader3 = new InvoiceHeader { Group = 'B', InvoiceLines = new List<InvoiceLine> { invoiceLine5, invoiceLine6 } };
var invoiceHeader4 = new InvoiceHeader { Group = 'B', InvoiceLines = new List<InvoiceLine> { invoiceLine7, invoiceLine8 } };

var invoiceHeaders = new List<InvoiceHeader>
{
    invoiceHeader1,
    invoiceHeader2,
    invoiceHeader3,
    invoiceHeader4
};
```

What I want to get is a Lists of invoiceLines for each Group.

So I would like for group A:

`invoice1`, `invoice2`, `invoice3` and `invoice4`

and for group B:

`invoice5`, `invoice6`, `invoice7` and `invoice8`

The furthest I got was:

```
var invoiceLinesGroupA = invoiceHeaders.SelectMany(x => x.InvoiceLines);
```

which as far as I can tell will get all eight invoiceLines. Somehow I need to discrimate by group to just get the ones for groupA and do likewise for groupB.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You may just want to group the invoice headers by the group:

```
var groups = invoiceHeader.GroupBy(ih => ih.Group);
```

Then you can access the lines of the groups:

```
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group " + group.Group);
    Console.WriteLine("Lines:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", group.SelectMany(h => h.InvoiceHeader.InvoiceLines)));
}
```

Output would be something like

```
Group A
Lines:
invoice1, invoice2, invoice3, invoice4

Group B
Lines:
invoice5, invoice6, invoice7, invoice8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regrouped = invoiceHeaders
    .SelectMany(
        header => header.InvoiceLines,
        (header, line) => new { header, line }
    )
    .GroupBy(
        o => o.header.Group,
        o => o.line,
        (groupName, lines) => new InvoiceHeader
        {
            Group = groupName,
            InvoiceLines = lines.ToList()
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this overload of [Enumerable.SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx)

```
var result = invoiceHeaders
               .SelectMany(x => x.InvoiceLines,
                           (group, InvoiceLine)=>{group, InvoiceLine})
               .Where(res => res.group='A');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
        var test = from h in invoiceHeaders
                   from i in h.InvoiceLines
                   group i by h.Group
                   into g
                   select new {key = g.Key, rows = g.ToArray()};
```

You can then access the items like this `test.Where(x => x.key == 'A').rows`

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = from current in myInvoiceHeaders
                join c in myInvoiceLines on current.Id equals c.Header.Id into linesByHeader                    
                select new {
                    Header = current,
                    Lines = linesByHeader
                };
```

should work under the premise that you have a criteria to join both entities.